# programing controls with identifier

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, custom-controls

I am having difficulties in programming controls based upon the value I get from the database. I can draw the controls all right but now I am trying to use a delegate to assign each of them an ID so I can later link them to an order.

Problem I am having is:

```
foreach (Control table in pTableList)
{
    if (!this.Controls.Contains(table))
    {
        this.Controls.Add(table);

        table.Click += new EventHandler(Table_Click); // 1
    }
}

[Category("Action")]
[Description("Table clicked.")]
public event TableClickedHandler TableClicked;

protected virtual void OnTableClicked(int pTableID)
{
    if (TableClicked != null)
    {
        TableClicked(pTableID);  // Notify Subscribers
    }
}

private void Table_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnTableClicked(1); // 2
}
```

It then shoots of and runs another method, but what I need is some sort of identifier for each of those created tables. Why cant I just do `sender.ID` ;) Notice I have had to hard code the `int` 1 at point `//2`, just to get it to work but this isn't useful, if the user clicked table 23!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can either use the `.Tag` property to store the identifier or just pass the actual table, which is in the `sender` parameter:

```
private void Table_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnTableClicked(sender as Table); // 2
}
```

I've used `Table` because I don't know exactly what's the actual type of your control - you should change it appropriately.

Comment: lol... thanks didnt think it would have been that simple thanks!